# Wait for fetching to be done untill returning data

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to get the returned data whenever fetching is done, because the correct timestamp will be there after fully fetching however the function will return the link with an empty timestamp instead of the latest timestamp of all the data.

```
async function pushData(url) {
  let settings = { method: "Get" };
  let timestamp = "";
  let i = 0;

  fetch(url, settings)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then((json) => {
        json.forEach(function (object) {
          console.log(object);
          i++;
        });
        timestamp = json[i-1].timestamp;
      });

  return await 'https://www.bitmex.com/api/v1/trade?count=1000&symbol=XBTUSD&startTime=' + timestamp;
}

var test = pushData('https://www.bitmex.com/api/v1/trade?count=1000&symbol=XBTUSD');
console.log(test);
```

Comment: Why don't you await the fetch, rather than a *string*?

Comment: try not mixing `await` and `.then`

Comment: You mean putting the await in front of fetch? That doesn't work.

Comment: usage: `const response = await fetch(URL);` , see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54555778/async-await-fetch-in-node-js) stackoverflow post

Comment: Does this answer your question? [async / await fetch in node-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54555778/async-await-fetch-in-node-js)

Comment: Well, returning happens before fetching data, still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must utilise JavaScript `Promise` here by using `async` / `await` as I have done so in the code below for you:

```js
async function pushData(url) {
  let settings = { method: "GET" };
  let timestamp = "";
  let i = 0;

  let res = await fech(url, settings)
  res = await res.json();

  res.forEach(function (object) {
    console.log(object);
    i++;
  });
  timestamp = res[i - 1].timestamp;

  return {
    res: res,
    timestamp: timestamp
  };
};

(async() => {
var test = await pushData('https://www.bitmex.com/api/v1/trade?count=1000&symbol=XBTUSD');
console.log(test);
console.log("Timestamp: " + test.timestamp)
console.log("Fetch Result: " + test.res)
})();
```

Since it this function is `async`, it returns a `Promise` which must be resolved as well. You didn't resolve it  - You never used `await` or `.then()` to resolve it.

Here are some resources which were provided in the comments: [async / await Stackoverflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54555778/async-await-fetch-in-node-js) [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: var test = await pushData is not possiblyed e, it is not in a function. Still the timestamp + fetch result is displayed first, then the data of variable test.

Comment: I answered this question assuming that it is; I will amend the answer to function globally right now.

Comment: I've just edited the question to resolve the issue which your comment highlighted.